# Resource Strings in JScript with classic ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jscript

I have the following JScript block, where I want to set a resource string from
a global resource file.

```
<script type="text/jscript" language="jscript">
    function DoSmthg(sender, args) {
        var message = "<%# MyDomain.Properties.Resources.MyString %>";
    }
</script>
```

But the variable always stays empty.
There are many good documentations about inline expressions, as 
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/976112/en-us I would have thought that

```
"<%= MyResource %>"
```

would be the correct one, but then I always get the error:
"The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Comment: change `"<%= MyResource %>"` to `"<%# MyResource %>"`

Comment: I did this. Then I get no error, but the variable is empty.

Comment: I think, my problem is described here:
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-Controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-ie.aspx

Is it possible to move the code to the client event, something like:

    <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) { blabla; message = '<%= MyDomain.Properties.Resources.MyString %>'; }" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

As stated in 
http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/The-Controls-collection-cannot-be-modified-because-the-control-contains-code-blocks-ie.aspx the problem is, that controls are added dynamical, and this is not possible if I use <%= ... %> inline tags.

I moved the jscript with inline expression to the control in the body, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('<%= GetGlobalResourceObject("Lang", "Interval")%>');
</script>
```

<%# <- this should be used to databind a boudable porperty of a server side control.